# AWS SQS - how to limit processing queue per minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

in AWS SQS how to limit processing queue per minute?

we have a scenario that we need to limit the calls to 3rd party API to be max 10 calls per minute. so our solution is to make that call Async using AWS SQS and Lambda function. but we know that we can apply delay to each queue but are there a way to limit queue per minute (max 10 receive queue per minute)?

Comment: Instead of letting SQS trigger lambda directly, set up a cron job in EventBridge to trigger lambda every minute.

Comment: There is no in-built way to enforce such a limit. Have you considered simply writing a program that runs on an EC2 instance and uses `sleep` to wait between processing each message?

Answer (score 0):

If you review the Trigger detail for your lambda function, you will see two very interesting values Batch size and Batch window, by default you will see that the value in size is 10, to be able to place different values you must remove the detail and add it again for the SQS queue, you could perhaps adjust the **Batch Window** so that it fulfills what you want to do.

https://aws.amazon.com/es/about-aws/whats-new/2020/11/aws-lambda-now-supports-batch-windows-of-up-to-5-minutes-for-functions/

As the source indicates, lambda will wait according to the time you indicate, adjusting that value in theory could make it fit within the minute, I hope it helps you.